# TextField Unnecessary Re-renders

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've noticed an issue where every component within the same parent (**App** in below example) will rerender when unrelated states/props change, making the page/forms noticeable slower.

I've followed many advice like memoizing event handlers & props, but unrelated components still re-renders. I'm stumped. What am I not understanding about React?

[[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-leaf-32fr7?file=/src/App.js)] In React debugger, enable: **Highlight updates when components render**

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

function MyTextInput(props) {
  return (
    <TextField
      variant={"outlined"}
      onChange={props.onChange}
      value={props.value}
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [exampleTextValue1, setExampleTextValue1] = useState("");
  const [exampleTextValue2, setExampleTextValue2] = useState("");

  const handleChange1 = useMemo(
    () => (event) => setExampleTextValue1(event.target.value),
    []
  );

  const handleChange2 = useMemo(
    () => (event) => setExampleTextValue2(event.target.value),
    []
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Change me:
        <MyTextInput value={exampleTextValue1} onChange={handleChange1} />
      </div>

      <div>
        Unrelated inputs. Should not re-render:
        <MyTextInput value={exampleTextValue2} onChange={handleChange2} />
        <MyTextInput value={exampleTextValue2} onChange={handleChange2} />
        {/*  to feel the impact, copy the above line like 98 more times  */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Edit: Added a console.log on the `MyTextField` component in the CodeSandbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debugger tools are bugged in regards to memoized components. When you memoize components they don't actually re-render, but the debugging tools highlights them anyway (see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19778).

To actually test the re-rendering, change the default state value for the second input (which is rendered lots of times) to something like "test", then put a `console.log` inside a memoized `MyTextInput` component to see which are actually getting re-rendered:

```
const MyTextInput = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log(props.value);
  return (
    <TextField
      variant={"outlined"}
      onChange={props.onChange}
      value={props.value}
      disabled={props.disabled}
    />
  );
});
```

You can see it prints the "test" value once for all the second inputs when they first render, then as you type in the first, it isn't logging all the second inputs `console.log`s thanks to the memoization.

Comment: I've added a console.log on the `MyTextField` component. Seems to confirm it's rerendering. Also wouldn't memoizing the resulting component get really messy to work with? We have too many places in code where props are dynamically computed, so I wouldn't be able to "watch" the props in a `memo(fn, [ enter, props, here ])` call.

Comment: I've tried memoizing like you did, & it seems to work like magic. Still need to figure out how this works.

Comment: Cool. Btw if you want to memoize functions use `useCallback`, that's what it's for. `useMemo` is for values. Here's an article that goes into more detail about why if you're interested: https://medium.com/@kevinwkds/react-memorized-hook-usecallback-usememo-react-memo-d11da7ebb9cc

Comment: That was it. `React.memo` did wonders. We also confirmed the Debugger does incorrectly highlights renders where renders don't happen. Thanks for the help!